# SKLabelNode subclass has zero frame

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Here I have a very straightforward implementation of a SKLabelNode subclass.

The interface:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface CSLabelNode : SKLabelNode

- (instancetype)initWithFontNamed:(NSString *)fontName fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize fontColor:(SKColor *)fontColor;

@end
```

The implementation:

```
#import "CSLabelNode.h"

@implementation CSLabelNode

- (instancetype)initWithFontNamed:(NSString *)fontName fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize fontColor:(SKColor *)fontColor
{
    self = [super initWithFontNamed:fontName];
    if (self) {
        self.fontSize = fontSize;
        self.fontColor = fontColor;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I am calling the regular SKLabelNode and my custom CSLabelNode like this:

```
CSLabelNode *custom = [[CSLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"CrimsonText-Bold" fontSize:30.0f fontColor:[SKColor redColor];
SKLabelNode *regular = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"CrimsonText-Bold"];

custom.text = @"Some text";
regular.text = @"Some text";
```

The problem is that the frame for my custom node is **origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=0, height=0)**, while the regular node's frame is, like expected: **origin=(x=-43, y=-1) size=(width=86, height=25)**

What do I have to do for my custom object to have a non-zero frame property?

Comment: Try putting that code in a SKLabelNode category. If all you want to do is to add a convenience initializer that would also be the preferred way.

Comment: Your code works. The custom label's height is 26 and its width is 136. BTW, you need to add a ] at the end of the custom allocation/initialization statement.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I will probably add more code to this, so a category may not be enough in the long run.

Comment: @0x141E The bracket got lost somewhere while typing the question, so that is not an issue. Neither are the width and height values – I just typed something in, sorry about that. Still it doesn't work for me. What environment do you use? I am working in XCode 6.1 and Yosemite DP8, so that may be an issue? I need to know the frame sizes as I am doing some calculations later in the code.

Comment: The code worked with Xcode 5.1.1 and 6 beta 4.